How can I prove or disprove the following statements? I had come up with solutions for both of them but apparently I was wrong.
The statements to prove or disprove are:
1)Let Y be a subset of the topological space X.If the interior of Y is connected, then Y is connected.
2)Let Y be a subset of the topological space X. If Y is connected, then the closure of Y is connected.
I had made the following attempts, trying to prove the contrapositives of the arguments in each:
"Since the interior of Y is the maximal open subset contained in Y, then if Z is an clopen subset of X then it should be contained in the interior as well.But the interior is connected, so it cannot have a clopen subset."
I suppose I should have made an argument about the Z being closed causing a contradiction as well.
My attempt to the second used the fact that the closure of Y was the minimal closed set containing Y.
Can you help me prove or disprove these statements using the having no nontrivial clopen subsets definition of connectedness?

Here is an example: $[0, 1)$ is a clopen subset of $[0, 1) \cup [2, 3]$, but it's not contained in the interior. Do you see why your argument was mistaken? (You should actually look for a counterexample for 1).)


is a standard result and you can find a proof in any book that deals with connectedness.


A simpler example for 1): $(0,1) \cup {2}$ in the real line.

But how do I show that the interior of X=(0,1] U [2,3] is connected. I see that [0,1) is open in X but why is it also closed?
